# Spring - @Autowire uma List com elementos

Tags: java, spring-boot

Tenho um controller que possui esse @Autowired:

```
@Autowired
Rules rules;
```

Essa classe Rules está definida da seguinte maneira:

```
@Service
public class Rules {

    @Autowired
    private List<RegistrationRule> allRules;

    public List<RegistrationRule> getAllRules() {
        return allRules;
    }
}
```

Eu quero que quando fazer o @Autowired na lista allRules ela já venha com alguns items padrões dentro dela, da seguinte maneira:

```
allRules.add( new EmployeePositionRule() );
allRules.add( new CostCenterRule() );
```

Eu tentei colocar no construtor da classe Rules da seguinte maneira:

```
public Rules() {
    allRules.add( new EmployeePositionRule() );
    allRules.add( new CostCenterRule() );
}
```

Mas se eu fizer assim uma exceção é lançada na hora de compilar o projeto:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'intRaptMecController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'rules'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'rules' defined in file [...validations\rules\Rules.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [validations.rules.Rules]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Qual a maneira correta de fazer isso?

Comment: `UnsatisfiedDependencyException` quer dizer que o Spring não sabe de onde vem uma dependência que precisa ser injetada. No seu caso, ele não sabe como injetar um `List<RegistrationRule>` na sua classe `Rules`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como o Leonardo Lima comentou, a `UnsatisfiedDependencyException` acontece porque o Spring não achou nenhum `Bean` do tipo `List<RegistrationRule>`. Para isso, você pode declarar um método que retorne os valores default que você precisa. Exemplo:

```
@Bean
public List<RegistrationRule> myDefaultRules() {
  List<RegistrationRule> defaultRules = new ArrayList();
  defaultRules.add(new EmployeePositionRule());
  defaultRules.add(new CostCenterRule());
  return defaultRules;
}
```

Reapre que a anotação `@Bean` serve para dizer para o Spring que você está provendo uma dependência, no caso a sua lista padrão de `RegistrationRule`.

Caso vocẽ queria que seja injetado valores diferentes na sua lista `allRules`, você precisará declarar outros `Beans` e utilizar a anotação `@Qualifier` para diferenciar entre qual lista de `RegistrationRule` você quer injetar. Exemplo:

```
@Bean(name = "defaultRules")
public List<RegistrationRule> myDefaultRules() {
  List<RegistrationRule> defaultRules = new ArrayList();
  defaultRules.add(new EmployeePositionRule());
  defaultRules.add(new CostCenterRule());
 return defaultRules;
}

@Bean(name = "otherRules")
public List<RegistrationRule> otherRules() {
  List<RegistrationRule> otherRules = new ArrayList();
  otherRules.add(new FooRule());
  otherRules.add(new MyOtherRule());
  return otherRules;
}

@Autowired
@Qualifier("defaultRules")
private List<RegistrationRule> defaultRules;

@Autowired
@Qualifier("otherRules")
private List<RegistrationRule> otherRules;
```

Espero ter ajudado!

EDIT 1:

Tente este exemplo.

```
@Configuration
public class RulesConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public List<RegistrationRule> allRules() {
        List<RegistrationRule> allRules = new ArrayList();
        allRules.add(new EmployeePositionRule());
        allRules.add(new CostCenterRule());
        return allRules;
    }

}

@Service
public class RuleService {

    @Autowired
    List<RegistrationRule> rules;

}
```

Comment: Mas onde eu devo colocar este código? Dentro da classe Rules? Ou no meu Controller? Eu coloquei dentro da classe Rules mas está disparando a mesma exceção :(

Comment: Teste se o código do EDIT 1 da resposta funciona para vocẽ.

Comment: @WitnessTruth, você precisa criar este `@Bean` dentro de uma classe anotada com `@Configuration`.

Comment: Bem observado @Dherik. Editei a resposta.

Comment: O detalhe de seu qualifier fez o que eu queria e ainda resolveu um problema que tive posteriormente ao adicionar outras regras. Com esse qualifier vai ser até bom para resolvermos outras coisas que poderemos enfrentar aqui. Obrigado

Answer (score 3):

A razão é simples.

O construtor da classe `Rules` é chamado **antes** de injetar o `List<RegistrationRule>` no campo `allRules`. Portanto, `allRules` estará sempre nulo.

Este seria seria o código atual, ainda com o problema:

```
@Service
public class Rules {

    @Autowired
    private List<RegistrationRule> allRules;

    public Rules() {
       allRules.add( new EmployeePositionRule() ); //allRules estará nulo!
       allRules.add( new CostCenterRule() );
    }

    public List<RegistrationRule> getAllRules() {
        return allRules;
    }
}
```

A correção pode ser fazer a **injeção por construtor** ou por método `set`. Aliás, evite usar `@Autowired` em campos privados (o famoso *Field Injection*), pois esta técnica de injeção é a menos recomendada por [diversos motivos](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/366225/172464), embora seja (infelizmente) muito comum.

Sendo assim, experimente fazer desta maneira:

```
@Service
public class Rules {

    private List<RegistrationRule> allRules;

    @Autowired
    public Rules(List<RegistrationRule> allRules) {
       allRules.add( new EmployeePositionRule() );
       allRules.add( new CostCenterRule() );
    }

    public List<RegistrationRule> getAllRules() {
        return allRules;
    }
}
```

Também confirme se seu `@Bean` de lista de `RegistrationRule` foi criado corretamente. Ele pode ser criado dentro de uma classe qualquer anotada com  `@Configuration` (`org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration`), desta forma:

```
@Configuration
public class RulesConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public List<RegistrationRule> allRules() {
       List<RegistrationRule> rules = new ArrayList();
       return rules;
    }

}
```

Comment: Fiz da maneira que vc respondeu. Entretanto, a lista allRules não cria uma instância, ficando "null" e lançando uma NullPointerException quando tento percorre-la usando a linha  for(RegistrationRule rule : rules.getAllRules())

Comment: @WitnessTruth, mostre na sua pergunta como você criou o `Bean` do `List<RegistrationRule>`. A resposta do Wellington mostra uma maneira de fazer isto e ter certeza que ela não virá nula. Assumi que a criação deste `List` estava correto na minha resposta. É provável que a minha resposta e a dele solucione o seu problema.

Comment: @WitnessTruth, veja um exemplo de criação do `allRules` como `Bean` para pode ser injetado.

Comment: Olá! Precisei retornar a questão pois coloquei exatamente da maneira que vc me mandou o código. Porém, como adicionei outras Rules, ao invés dele pegar só as Rules que coloquei dentro do construtor, ele pega todas as Rules que estão dentro do pacote. Não entendo o por que disso estar acontecendo

Comment: Olá! Como assim? Qual pacote? Se entendi o que quer dizer, você está adicionando novas rules no construtor e elas estão sendo adicionadas a lista e sendo passadas para outras classes?

Comment: No meu projeto tenho um pacote chamado "rules" e nele está a classe Rules (@Service) com o mesmo código que você me passou, uma interface RegistrationRule com 1 método validate(Apontamento apontamento) e outras 7 que são classes que "implements" essa interface (RegistrationRule).

Comment: Só que no construtor eu coloquei para que só 3 dessas 7 classes estivessem na lista. Mas mesmo assim está adicionando todas as 7.

Comment: Você está adicionado estas outras 4 em alguma outra classe, correto @WitnessTruth?

Comment: Não estou. A única coisa que fiz com essa classe Rules foi dar um @Autowired em um Controller e usar um Loop na lista que o metodo getAllRules() retorna.

Comment: @WitnessTruth, recomendo criar uma nova pergunta para poder mostrar os detalhes da implementação. Entendo que isto é um novo problema.